# Exporting highlights from Kindle Personal Documents to a TXT file

Tags: ipad, windows, kindle

There are two main categories in Kindle App for iPad:

- Books - contains books purchased from Amazon; highlights are available at https://kindle.amazon.com/your_highlights — it works fine for me.
- Personal Documents - contains all other books; highlights are not available online.

So, I have book purchased at different source than Amazon and I would like to be able to export my highlights and notes to a text file (or any other common format). My approaches so far:

- As far as I know, https://kindle.amazon.com/your_highlights is available for Books category and thus, for Amazon-purchased books only. There are no entries from "Personal Documents"
- I cannot move my book from Personal Document to Books - there is no such option in Kindle App. There is no such option on Amazon's "Manage Your Kindle" site too.
- There is no option to export all highlights. Kindle app has option to share a highlight via Facebook or Twitter, but there is no option for copy or export it.

I synced my book with Kindle Touch and highlights are synced successfully. But:

- There is no export option in Kindle Touch too.
- I am unable to read highlights content on my cpu. The file with highlights has extension `.azw3r` and contains relative references, for example: `annotation.personal.highlight 283390 283606`.
- There are no entries in `My Clippings` text file (there are entries there but for non-synced books).

The question is: **How can I export my highlights and notes from iPad Kindle App to a TXT or any other common file?**

*Note I'm using Windows but I put this question to Apple.SE since the root problem comes from iPad.*

Comment: Basically it's a Kindle problem but let's see whether anybody has an answer.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this??

Comment: @Giuliano: Unfortunately - not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Bookcision](http://www.norbauer.com/bookcision/).Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Bookcision doesn't work because the book doesn't appear on "Your books" collection. Snippefy is a paid solution; I'm looking for a free one.

Comment: Snippefy seems defunct, and Snippefy.com is a spam domain now.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works previous to iOS 8.3, wish I knew what to do on 8.4 though! :

1. Download & install an app such as [iFunBox Classic](http://dl.i-funbox.com/) (free). This app allows you to explore your iPhone files with no jailbreak required.

   Plug your iPhone/iPad into PC via USB and start iFunBox Classic.

   In iFunBox, navigate to "User Applications/Kindle/Library".

   Copy the file "AnnotationStorage" to your computer.

`AnnotationStorage` is an SQL database and can be read with a free app such as [SQLiteBrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/).